# Down-vote on the way to the epic badge

Tags: support, reputation, badges, down-votes, daily-reputation-badges

Yesterday was the third time I've reached 200 points in one day. Maybe this is a bit early to ask as I still have a long way to go to the "Epic" badge, but the thing is that when I woke up this morning I found out that one of my answers was down voted. The -2 points was still accounted for yesterday which brought me to just 198 points and not to 200.

Is the count towards the epic badge now back to 2 days? Or does this day still count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Downvotes no longer count towards the 200 rep badges (Mortarboard, Epic, Legendary).](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/181103/169611)

So you can get to 200 from positive rep and then downvoted into oblivion and still have the day count towards those badges.

Comment: What if I removed the answer? (Because it was indeed wrong, I got that just later). I removed it today.

Comment: Then it probably wouldn't count. I'm not 100% sure though.

Comment: @Avi I believe the day still counts if the reputation doesn't get reversed. If it does, then the day gets recalculated as if the reputation never existed, so I don't believe it would.

Comment: @animuson - Not sure I got your answer :/

Comment: @Avi If your post is over 60 days old (I think, maybe it's 90, I can't remember) and has a score more than 2, the reputation is not reversed when it gets deleted. So that would very likely count towards the badges. In cases where the reputation *does* get reversed, the system acts as if the reputation was never awarded in the first place, so it's unlikely that it would count.

Comment: @animuson - Got it now. I re-reversed it. Hope this day still counts. Anyway, I've got a long way ahead. Not sure I'll ever get to the end anyway :)