# Could "(the daily maximum)" be removed from the Mortarboard description?

Tags: feature-request, badges, daily-reputation-badges, badge-description

On the [badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) page, the Mortarboard badge is described as:

> Earned at least 200 reputation (the [daily maximum](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)) in a single day

Is this not misleading in its wording? It implies that you *must* hit the reputation cap to be awarded the badge, instead of just having your reputation gain from everything (excluding cast/received downvotes and association bonuses). Could this be changed to be something like:

> Earned at least 200 reputation (excluding downvotes) in a single day

Answer (score 5):

The badge award is something you see, and since it's the first time you have crossed that reputation threshold, it's also likely that it's the first time you'll see votes without any value (since you hit the cap).  The link serves to educate people about the reputation cap that they are seeing kick in for the first time.

Comment: Rep from accepted answers is not counted towards the daily maximum but is counted for the badge. This is probably the most common point of confusion.

Comment: You can even earn this badge [from bounties alone](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260072/mortarboard-badge-is-awarded-due-to-bounty-award), again leading to confusion.

Comment: You can also earn this badge without ever having crossed the threshold of having increased your rep on a site by 200 in a day, if you have received and/or cast downvotes earlier in the day. [This is why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/181103/287315).