# Why didn't I get the Mortarboard badge again after I achieved 227 in a single day?

Tags: support, badges, daily-reputation-badges

Why didn't I get the Mortarboard badge again even though I achieved 227 in a single day (18-01-2018)?

Removing the tag wiki of 4, it still stands at 223.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/7429447/debanjanb?tab=reputation

Yes, I have gone through the discussion [Why don't I have the “Mortarboard” badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173381/why-dont-i-have-the-mortarboard-badge). But the scenario in that question is totally different.

Comment: Because you already have that tag: https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/144/mortarboard?userid=7429447

Comment: There is no duplicate of this question here as far as I could find (i.e. the same answer), and the badge page doesn't make it clear it's awarded only once.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/168333). Ctrl-F to "Mortarboard" and it says "bronze; awarded once".

Comment: @S.L.Barth You can't find it if you're just looking on the help center or the badges list on a site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The badge is awarded only once per user, not multiple times. All badges that aren't explicitly stated as being awarded multiple times are only awarded once.

As rene said, you already [earned the badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/144/mortarboard?userid=7429447) on January 11. As such, you can't earn it again even if you meet the criteria again.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the short and distinct explanation.